# can i share itunes db between windows 7 and osx on the same computer?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, itunes

i have itunes installed on apple snow.
can i use that same music location for my itunes in windows 7 that's on the same computer? 
i can read hfs partitions on my windows 7. i want to be able to add songs using the windows 7 itunes and that they will be auto added to the mac itunes database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you've installed Boot Camp and are running Windows 7 along with Snow Leopard on the same machine. While the Boot Camp drivers allow you to read HFS+ partitions, they do not allow you to write to them. Therefore, one approach is to use [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/), which enables read/write support for HFS+ partitions in Windows. Using MacDrive, [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/09/05/sharing-your-itunes-library-between-os-x-and-windows/) are some instructions for setting it up such that you can access your OS X iTunes library from Windows.

Another option is to store the entire library on a third partition or an external drive, and have both OS X and Windows point to it.